# Keycloak theme, after clicking on ${client.baseUrl}, clientId changes

Tags: keycloak

I wrote a theme for a keycloak in ftl. in several places I use `${client.baseUrl}` as a return to the login page, unfortunately after clicking this link clientId changes to account and not to the correct client in the context of which login is taking place.

I will add that I use `rootUrl` and `baseUrl` the same in my client as in the client `account`. Does this cause a problem with losing client information?

How can I solve this problem?